# Online/Offline App in Angular

Tags: javascript, web-services, angularjs, dependency-injection

I am developing an application in Angular that makes many calls to a couple of webservices. I want to develop an offline component to the app such that it will cache certain webservice results to LocalStorage and use them when the connection is offline.

That part is fairly simple, and the part I am having the most trouble with is how to branch logically when the app is offline.

Here is my current flow:

1. User loads the page
2. Webservice calls happen as usual
3. $http interceptor looks for a 404 error and marks a `$rootScope.isOnline` boolean flag to indicate we are offline, otherwise if no 404 then we mark as online

I want my code to branch depending on this flag, in a way that is maintainable. As such, I was looking at using dependency injection to inject either an 'online' service which makes calls to the webservice, or an 'offline' service, which interfaces with the LocalStorage results if they exist.

Can I base my dependency injection based off the online/offline flag to inject the correct service like so?

```
.factory('AuthService', ['$rootScope', '$injector', function($rootScope, $injector) {
    if($rootScope.isOnline) {
        return $injector.get('OnlineAuthService');
    }
    else {
        return $injector.get('OfflineAuthService');
    }
}])

.service('OnlineAuthService', ['$rootScope', '$http', '$location', 'serviceEndpoint', 'securityEndpoint', 'organisationId', function ($rootScope, $http, $location, serviceEndpoint, securityEndpoint, organisationId) {
    this.ensureSession = function (data) {
        // Do some connection to the webservice
    };
}])

.service('OfflineAuthService', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
    this.ensureSession = function (data) {
        // Do some LocalStorage stuff
    };
}])

AuthService.ensureSession(data);
```

The issue I am having is that `$rootScope.isOnline` is not marked as offline before the first call to my webservice, so even when the connection is offline, the dependency injection looks at `$rootScope.isOnline` and injects the OnlineAuthService.

Is this the correct way of developing an Online/Offline app in Angular or is there a better way?

Comment: Basically I would approach this by creating a faux interface in JavaScript that takes both services and at run-time determines which one to use.  This way that service can be injected before it's known whether or not the application is online.  I would also have it handle internally making the initialization calls to avoid dealing with race conditions from controllers trying to get initial data.

Comment: @shaunhusain sounds interesting... can you please share an example of how that would work?

Comment: Here is a plnkr with more detailed code: http://plnkr.co/edit/BXyZVU7uoKkJO4KQOs3R?p=info

Comment: could do your intital test before initializing angular ( don't auto initialize angular) and pass global variables from test to your service. Call angular bootstrap once your test is done... I think this about what @shaunhusain is suggesting. Also not sure you get a 401 when offline do you?

Comment: @charlietfl guess I could do it this way, saw the angular bootstrap method earlier, but was trying to avoid global variables and go for a more Angular way if I could. I get a 404 when offline, not a 401.

Comment: it's not like one global variablethat you can give a very unique property name to  will pollute much and to me it saves a lot of other deferred coding

Comment: You would have to be online to get a 404. If you are offline the `$http` request will not complete.Not sure what the error is at that point in the context of angular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. Take a look at this simplified plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/CpiJaF480Mai050b63RC?p=preview

The idea there is that you have the singleton service object returned by the service, but then you copy over different function methods as online/offline changes.

There are many other ways to do this, such as adding levels of indirection (creating a service from which you can request the current active service for example).

You can not simply do it with angular injection, because both factory and service calls will get called once and only once and will simply register a single instance for the service name (they will not get called every time you inject).

Comment: This is great and works perfectly, thank you so much for taking the time and giving me an example!

Comment: Yup this is basically what I was saying except maybe having a service that just has the same "interface" er functions as the end implementation requires.  What's shown in the example here is the same thing just having both services with the same functions available and switching which one to use based on the current state of the is online property.  You may want the "AuthService" to also depend on some other services to make calls to "reinitialize" with data if the state of Online changes at some point.

Comment: This is great, but is there a way to achieve the same in a more 'angular way'.  I.e. encapsulating the `registerOnlineOfflineService` method within a factory/provider rather than polluting the global namespace?

Comment: By globlal namespace do you meean the $rootScope? If yes, then sure, just change the $watch to watch a function on the service rather than placing isOnline on the scope.